# Mysql Auto Increment Different Tables

Tags: mysql, database, auto-increment

I have several tables keeping ai. One of table starts with 1000, one of it 2000, and its going like 3000,4000,5000. So I don't want them to overlap so start again from the beginning. I mean if number 2999 row inserted to the table, the next row shouldn't start with 3000 and go back to beginning. For example if 2128 is deleted some day, then overwrite it the new row.

Comment: Bad idea.  Simply use billions (or trillions) instead of thousands.

Comment: This is not what *identifiers* are for.  I suspect there is something fundamentally wrong with your design here.  Why on Earth would you want to *re-use* identifiers?  Why should your tables *never* contain more than 1,000 records?  Is the system going to *automatically delete* the 1st record when the 1001st insert is performed?  Does the owner of that record know this?  Are these tables related in any way?  What happens when a parent record is automatically deleted?  Are all of the child records going to be deleted?  Will abandoned child records now have a *new* parent record?

Comment: So how can I fix this problem, the certain thing is this, the tables will be more than one. And auto increment shouldnt overlap after insert.

Comment: Agree with those above - bad db design. But if you really think this is the right strategy then you'll have to use something like PHP to manage this 'number' and do all the 'if this happens, then do this to the number....'. Good luck.

Comment: Should I keep the ai column on another table and insert that to the tables?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? Asking this because perhaps a different solution might be more appropriate?

Comment: Creating a listing website and there are many categories. Actually the id should be 10 digits so start from 1000000000. Subcategories will be on different tables. So some of them will start from 2000000000, some of them from 2500000000 maybe, and 3000000000,4000000000....... @user1327961

Comment: @codeigniter It may be that you're creating too many unnecessary tables. You can give a starting value to `AUTO_INCREMENT` in a table, but it's relevant to that table alone. If you go with a set of pre-determined starting points in separate, ever increasing lists, it's only a matter of time that an overlap would occur somewhere causing a complete chaos in the logic involved. It's not quite clear as to why you don't want each table to have its own `AUTO_INCREMENT`, which would start from `1` and keep incrementing from there on.

Comment: so table categories (category_id, category_name) and subcategories (subcategory_id, category_id, subcategory_name) ? What's the rationale on different tables to hold all the category ids?

Comment: The id should be unique because I'm gonna stamp it to the images as watermark. @user1327961